# Spectral Norm of $2\times 2$ symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Consider a $2\times 2$ symmetric matrix, in this case, is there some closed formula for its spectral norm ?

By spectral norm I mean the induced 2-norm, there is a definition [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the square root of the largest (in magnitude) eigenvalue of $A^2$. Since $A^2$ is $2 \times 2$, the eigenvalues are given by the roots of a quadratic,  which you can work out. You might not like the "max", in which case you can avoid it by replacing it with

$$
max(x, y) = \frac{x+y+ |y-x|}{2}
$$
in your formula.

If 
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{bmatrix}
$$
then $A^2$ is 
$$
A^2 = \begin{bmatrix} a^2 + b^2 & b(a+c) \\ b(a+c) & c^2 + b^2 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and its characteristic polynomial is
$$
p(x) = x^2 - (a^2 + 2b^2 + c^2) x + (ac-b^2)^2.
$$
The roots are then 
$$
x = \frac{- (a^2 + 2b^2 + c^2) \pm \sqrt{ (a^2 + 2b^2 + c^2)^2 - 4(ac-b^2)^2}}{2}
$$
The greater root (in absolute value) is the one with the $-$ sign. (No need for the max trick in this case, because the coefficient of $x$ in the quadratic is so obviously negative). So that leads to your answer: the 2-norm is 
$$
\sqrt{\frac{ (a^2 + 2b^2 + c^2) + \sqrt{ (a^2 + 2b^2 + c^2)^2 - 4(ac-b^2)^2}}{2}}
$$

Comment: I was looking for a formula that would work without having to choose one of two values. Your formula looks exactly what I need, thanks.